# Add title to webpage from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, file, search

I have a table in my database that has a page title, keywords, images and other content for every page. I want to write some code in PHP and MySQL to fetch that data and create the file that is an HTML or PHP file (by fetching the file name stored in table) and write the code to fetch the page title and other content for page into the file one by one for each row, so that if later on I want to increase one column in any page, I may able to do so by increasing one field or table only.

Comment: table has fields as id, page_title, keywords, heading, description , history, picture, link and tags

Answer (score 0):

Why write out files when you can just have one page that examines the URL to determine what data from the database to use when returning the HTML?

You can see that StackOverflow has hundreds of thousands of question and answer webpages, but there is only one file serving all these pages. They are not saving a file for every question onto a hard drive.

Comment: off the track, I will like to see how SO scales and handles this much of traffic and know more about architecture, can you point me to some resource?

Comment: @Dan It is not a question website it is actually a information portal with sections divided and I want to design a pretty small and very simple from the users point , so that if a normal net user type of person can easily fill a form through admin panel and click few links and button and add pages to website, title of the page as entered by the admin and Dan I would really appreciate any other ideas also but firstly and to code for this algorithm .

Comment: @ashish Right. There are many CMS's designed for web designers to let their clients easily add and edit pages like that. Have you ever tried WordPress, Drupal, and the other popular open source CMS's? They let novices add pages, with titles and content and images and such. They also do not write any static files. There is no need to.

Comment: @Dan, thanks for pointing in right direction, I feel so stupid could have done googling

Comment: @Dan I don't want to use any CMS as I want it to be really simple select category and fill a form and page should created and add to website under appropriate category.

Comment: @ashish I was not suggesting you have to use a CMS. I was suggesting that like those CMS's, yours does not need to write static files. You just need one script that displays the title and content from the database based on the URL. If this is still not clear, then I doubt we will overcome the understanding barrier today, so I will leave you to your project. You will be implementing something like it is 1999 instead of 2011.